# Is it possible to prove $p\rightarrow\diamond (p\land q)$ in modal logic?

Tags: proof-theory, modal-logic

I need to prove $p\rightarrow\diamond (p\land q)$ in B axiomatic, which contains next conversion rules:
1.$(p\land q)\rightarrow(q\land p)$
2.$(q\land p)\rightarrow p$
3.$p\rightarrow(p\land p)$
4.$p\land(q\land r)\rightarrow(p\land q)\land r$
5.$p\rightarrow \lnot(\lnot p)$
6.$(p\land q)\land(q\land r)\rightarrow(p\land r)$
7.$(p\land(p\rightarrow q))\rightarrow q$
8.$\diamond(p\land q)\rightarrow\diamond p$

Comment: It goes against the guidelines of this site to change your question to a different one after it has been answered. You can ask another question to reflect the edited content, and that is perfectly acceptable. I have edited the question to bring back the original statement that was answered below.

Comment: No problem, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

**This answers the question as it was before it was edited to ask something completely different!**

If those are all the axioms you have, then no. The axioms are all true in an interpretation where $\Diamond p$ is false for all $p$, and in such an interpretation $p\to\Diamond(p\land q)$ will be false whenever $p$ is true.

On the other hand, it looks rather unlikely that those are really all the axioms you have. Most of them look like a randomish collection of algebraic properties of conjunction, but there seems to be nothing that allows you to reason much about implication. And apparently the *only* thing you can do with negation there is to introduce double negations; none of your rules say *anything* about negations that *aren't* doubled.

Are you really sure that's all of your rules?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No, that is not all of my rules. Actually, I need to prove some other theory. I edited my answer

Comment: I wanted to know about that way, but now you told me that it's impossible.

Comment: @Romadja: Your rules still appear to be woefully incomplete. As far as I can see, you can't even prove $p\to p$.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to write this rule, cause it is taken as a standard. I'll create a new answer. Thank you